# Which MPI package should I install?

Tags: package-management, kubuntu

I want to attempt some simple programs using MPI on my desktop which runs KUbuntu 10.04.2.  Which MPI package should I install?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's just for simple usage on your own system, OpenMPI is very nice, as it doesn't require any setup after installation, just running your application with `mpirun` is sufficient.

```
sudo aptitude install libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a [great Guide in the Ubuntu Community Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) on using the [MPICH2](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpich2/) implementation of the MPI. It's a bit old (the Guide I mean), but it should still work as described.

The specific package you're interested in there is [[image] mpich2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/mpich2).